# Automate windows page from linux through Java code

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium. I have to automate the page on windows machine from a linux machine Using java code.As per suggested i am using selenium grid. I registered hub and node on separate windows machines(For testing purpose).and to open the webpage on node I am using the following code :

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://ipaddress_hub:4444/wd/hub"),capability);
baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But i am getting error as

```
Error forwarding the new session new session request for webdriver should contain a location header with the session.
```

Do i need to define capabilities for browser and version?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate plz?

Comment: Can i use this example https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2?